# Bash - create an array with wildcard elements for matching

Tags: bash, syntax, sh

I would like to create an array as following to check if the output filename match with the pattern in the array.

```
declare -a arr=('class*_1n_*000000.txt','class*_1n_*010000.txt','class*_2n_*010000.txt','class*_2n_*012000.txt','class*_3n_*235000.txt')

if [[ "${arr[*]}"==$output_filename ]]; then
   echo $output_filename exist in arr
   #do something...
else
   echo $output_filename not exist in arr
   #do something...
fi
```

I have tried the following 3 cases and the comment would be my expected outcome

```
output_filename='class_2n_20180922012000.txt' #exist
output_filename='classA_2n_20180923012000.txt' #exist
output_filename='classA_4n_20180923012000.txt' #not exist
```

but all three cases return exist.

How can I solve this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You need to write an explicit loop. Using a wildcard won't automatically try all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, let's fix a couple of basic shell syntax problems first. The array declaration:

```
declare -a arr=('class*_1n_*000000.txt','class*_1n_*010000.txt','class*_2n_*010000.txt','class*_2n_*012000.txt','class*_3n_*235000.txt')
```

doesn't work because bash doesn't use commas to delimit the elements of an array, it uses whitespace. Since there's no whitespace in there, the shell will treat that as one large array element, which happens to contain some commas. You want this:

```
declare -a arr=('class*_1n_*000000.txt' 'class*_1n_*010000.txt' 'class*_2n_*010000.txt' 'class*_2n_*012000.txt' 'class*_3n_*235000.txt')
```

Second, the comparison:

```
if [[ "${arr[*]}"==$output_filename ]]; then
```

isn't doing anything at all like what you want. Again, whitespace is a delimiter in shell syntax, and since there's no whitespace around it, the `==` isn't treated as an operator, it's just part of a single long string. And `[[ somestring ]]` tests to see whether the string is non-blank, and since that string isn't blank, the test always comes out as true. Now, the obvious fix for this:

```
if [[ "${arr[*]}" == $output_filename ]]; then
```

...at least does a comparison, but not the comparison you want. It's treating the entire contents of the array (with all elements stuck together with spaces between, because that's what `[*]` does) as a single string, and seeing if it matches `$output_filename`, where `$output_filename` is treated as a wildcard pattern. But you wanted the array elements treated as wildcard patterns, so you'd need to reverse it:

```
if [[ "$output_filename" == ${arr[*]} ]]; then
```

...but that's *still* not what you want, because it's checking to see if `$output_filename` matches *all* of the entries in `arr` stuck together. In order for it to match, `$output_filename` would have to be a list of five filenames, separated by spaces, with the first matching `class*_1n_*000000.txt`, the second matching `class*_1n_*010000.txt`, etc. You need to compare the filename against each of the array elements one-at-a-time, and keep track of whether you've found a match. Something like this:

```
found_match="false"
for pattern in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$output_filename" == $pattern ]]; then
        found_match="true"
        break
    fi
done
if [[ "$found_match" == true ]]; then
   echo "$output_filename exist in arr"
   #do something...
else
   echo "$output_filename not exist in arr"
   #do something...
fi
```

Note that `"${arr[@]}"` (note the double-quotes and `@`) expands to each element of the array, with each treated as a separate string (so `for` will iterate over them). Also, I put double-quotes around the strings to be printed; you almost always want double-quotes around variable references (or things containing variable references) to avoid unexpected wildcard expansions and such. There is an exception here, though: in `[[ "$output_filename" == $pattern ]]`, the `$pattern` must be left unquoted so it's treated as a wildcard pattern rather than a fixed string.